# Existe alguma maneira de dar display a uma txt file sem o JFileChooser?

Tags: java

Existe alguma maneira de dar display a uma txt file sem o JFileChooser ?
Por exemplo escrevendo  a localizacao do .txt file e conectando directamente com o JTextArea

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer?

Comment: Você pode criar uma referência a um arquivo a partir de qualquer String fazendo `new File(caminho)`, onde `caminho` pode ser o conteúdo de qualquer campo texto. Seria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segue abaixo duas boas referencias e um código exemplo.

DevMedia - Lendo dados de Txt com Java:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/lendo-dados-de-txt-com-java/23221

Caelum - Lendo arquivos texto em Java com Scanner:
http://blog.caelum.com.br/lendo-arquivos-texto-em-java/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Informe o nome de arquivo texto:\n");
    String caminhoArquivo = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("\nConteúdo do arquivo texto:\n");

    try {
        try (FileReader arquivo = new FileReader(caminhoArquivo)) {
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arquivo);

            // lê a primeira linha
            // a variável "linha" recebe o valor "null" quando o processo
            // de repetição atingir o final do arquivo texto
            String linha = lerArq.readLine();

            while (linha != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s\n", linha);     
                linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado foi mesmo desse jeito que estava apensar fazer !